# Difference in data that Vue collects from Laravel API call versus what Laravel sends in its response

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

In my Vue app I make a call to a Laravel API. The console.log below is from Vue and shows a data object that is embedded in the data received in the Vue app from the API call. Note that the enquiry_type in the object summary, 'Something Else', differs to the enquiry_type when the object is expanded, 'Gyrotonic Sessions'...

```
{id: 5, created_at: null, updated_at: null, enquiry_type: 'Something Else'}
created_at: null
enquiry_type: "Gyrotonic Sessions"
id: 5
updated_at: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

When I check the request through Laravel's Telescope then the response is as I expected - the enquiry_type being 'Something Else', the id is 5 and the remainder of the data is fine. When it gets to the Vue app though the enquiry_type becomes 'Gyrotonic Sessions' in exploded object but not the object summary. The remainder of the data is correct.

This happens with other enquiry_types, all of the data is correct in the summary object and the detail object with the exception of the enquiry_type, which is correct in the summary object but in the detail the enquiry_type is changed to 'Gyrotonic Sessions'.

I don't manipulate the data before dumping it to the console.

Does anybody have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks. Complete hash on my part. Managed to set the value of the variable in a conditional test using = rather than ===. That's 36 hours of my life i'll never get back again!